# Junit test terminates with ADT

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I build most of an app in standard eclipse on a linux box. Later I wanted to work on it from home, so imported into eclipse (ADT version) on my mac at home. Should be no problems right? Nope. I'm trying to run some test cases, but they get terminated before anything happens. I had the test cases running fine on linux. There isn't any mention of Junit in any of the logs I've searched and the error the console gives is not very helpful:

```
<terminated> JUnit .. /path/to/java/binary
```

I'm on osx 10.9, Junit is in the buildpath, same results with stock eclipse. This is a problem with not with the code, there's just something I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the same version of JUnit on the two machines.  Different versions have different ways of identifying both the test classes and the test methods in those classes.  If you move your project from one version of JUnit to another you wouldn't technically have any test cases anymore.